# ASP.Net and Windows RT Image Upload

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working on a ASP.net (C#) website that has a form where the user inputs information, it also allows the user to upload a picture. I was thinking on storing the image path on the database (sql server 2008 r2) and save the image to the file system. Recently we spoke about the possibility to create a WinRT version. I don't know how the RT development manages the upload of an image, what would be the best approach to cover both versions, saving the image to the file system or saving the image directly to the database?

Comment: Did you solve your problem with my answer? if it is, please kindly accept answer, or ask again your problem in detail :)

Comment: My apologies, yes it solved my problem.

Comment: great to hear that you solved :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional `MultipartFormData` POST can be implemented with WinRT.
Below codes are implemented based on the `Portable Class Library (PCL)`, a kind of subset of WinRT and .NET, but it would be 99% same.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// upload file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> UploadedFile(string filename, StreamContent streamContent)
    {
        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) & (streamContent != null)) != true)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No filename or streamContent");
        }

        // 1. File upload
        const string uploadUrl = "image/upload.ajax";

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent { { streamContent, "file", filename } };

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content,
            RequestUri = new Uri(uploadUrl, UriKind.Relative)
        };

        var fileUploadResult = await _httpClient.SendAsync(message);

                    // Please change below response message treatment.
                    var result = await fileUploadResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var fileUplaodJsonResult = JObject.Parse(result);
        var uploadedFileUrl = fileUplaodJsonResult["url"].Value<string>();
        Debug.WriteLine("upload: " + fileUplaodJsonResult["success"].Value<string>());

        // 2. Post image url that you posted and other messages.
        const string confirmUrl = "image/confirm.ajax";

        var confirmValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                              {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("url", uploadedFileUrl),
// Put other messages to post


                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("rotate", "0"), 
                             };

        var confirmResult = await _httpClient.PostAsync(confirmUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(confirmValue));
               // Please change below response message treatment.
        var confirmJsonResult = JObject.Parse(await confirmResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return confirmJsonResult["url"].Value<string>();
    }
```

And, you can now use it as `var uploadedFileUrl = await UploadedFile(fileNameOrUrl, stream);`